# when I crosscompile objects, then binary file abnormal size

Tags: c, gcc, arm, embedded, cross-compiling

All object files have sizes smaller than 150Kb. However, when I cross-compile these object files, then the resulting ELF file size is 8.2Mb, that is about 55 times bigger...

Why is this happening?

[image: (Linux ARM) CrossCompile result..]

Comment: Plz click the enter image description here

Comment: Chances are this is because the binary is statically linked, so as well as perhaps adding startup code, the linker includes whatever library functions your application needs. You don't see these in any of the object files you give to the linker.

Comment: use [readelf](https://linux.die.net/man/1/readelf) to see the content of output file: `readelf -a freeRTOS-rtsm`